# I want to fetch images and I did it but in the wrong way

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to this so the answer might be simple and Idk.

I have two tables called `profile_images` and `users`. In pf I have a column called `image`. In users I have one called `img_id` which connects with `image` column.

I found this code on youtube and it does work but it fetchs the image based on the user id and not the `img_id`. I tried replacing `ur.id` with `ur.img_id` and it gives me an error. Pls help me.

```
SELECT pf.image, ur.username
FROM profile_images pf
INNER JOIN users ur 
ON ur.id = pf.id;
```

Comment: *"I tried replacing ur.id with ur.img_id and it gives me an error."* - Please elaborate on that.  Because according to the description that should work.  (Despite a variety of confused terminology you're using.)  Ultimately you're going to need to indicate the exact table structures and how your query isn't working as expected.

Comment: `I have two databases`...you mean `tables`, not databases. A database is the thing which contains the tables (and views, procedures, functions etc etc etc.)

Comment: `i have a row called image`....you mean a `column`, not a row. Rows are horizontal, columns are vertical

Comment: Also, you _probably_ shouldn't be storing image files (like JPEGs, PNGs, etc) _inside_ a database table (either using the antiquated `image` data-type, or the more modern `varbinary` type) because of IO performance reasons, especially in web-applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question, you have the following two tables

```
table users : id , ... , img_id
table profile_images : id , image
```

So it becomes your query

```
select p.image, u.username 
from users u join profile_images p on u.img_id = p.id
```